# eBay Trading API error: You need to create a seller's account

Tags: php, paypal, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm using [eBay PHP SDK](http://devbay.net/sdk/guides/)

When i try to add fixedprice item to sandbox - everything is OK, then I just change the credentials to Production mode and get an error:

> You need to create a seller's account. Before you can list this item
>   we need some additional information to create a seller's account.

How to fix this error? I have seller account with linked PayPal account (and money inside), but i'm not sure that i'm using the same account, becouse i made account for Developer program. 
***How to use my seller account in developer program?***

Please help.

The code that I have is below:

```
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
//Trading API
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Enums;

//Fiding API
//use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Services;
//use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types;

class EbayController extends BaseController {

    protected $TOKEN = 'Token here';
    protected $service;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->service = new Services\TradingService(array(
            'apiVersion' => '911',
            'siteId' => 0,
            'appId' => 'My app id here',
            'sandbox' => false,
            'certId' => 'My cert id here',
            'devId' => 'My dev id here',
                //'debug' => true
        ));
    }

    function test()
    {
        $this->addProductFixedPrice();
        echo '<br />//-------------------------------------------------<br />';




        $request = new Types\GeteBayOfficialTimeRequestType();
        $request->RequesterCredentials = new Types\CustomSecurityHeaderType();
        $request->RequesterCredentials->eBayAuthToken = $this->TOKEN;
        $response = $this->service->geteBayOfficialTime($request);

        if ( $response->Ack !== 'Success' )
        {
            if ( isset($response->Errors) )
            {
                foreach ( $response->Errors as $error )
                {
                    printf("ShortMessage Error: %s\n", $error->ShortMessage . '<br />');
                    printf("LongMessage Error: %s\n", $error->LongMessage . '<br />');
                    printf("ErrorClassification Error: %s\n", $error->ErrorClassification . '<br />');
                    printf("ErrorCode Error: %s\n", $error->ErrorCode . '<br />');
                    //printf("ErrorParameters Error: %s\n", $error->ErrorParameters . '<br />');
                    printf("SeverityCode Error: %s\n", $error->SeverityCode . '<br />');
                    printf("UserDisplayHint Error: %s\n", $error->UserDisplayHint . '<br />');
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf($response->Ack . "    --   The official eBay time is: %s\n", $response->Timestamp->format('H:i (\G\M\T) \o\n l jS F Y'));
        }
    }

    function addProductFixedPrice()
    {
        $request = new Types\AddFixedPriceItemRequestType();
        /**
         * An user token is required when using the Trading service.
         *
         * For more information about getting your user tokens, see:
         * http://devbay.net/sdk/guides/application-keys/
         */
        $request->RequesterCredentials = new Types\CustomSecurityHeaderType();
        $request->RequesterCredentials->eBayAuthToken = $this->TOKEN;
        /**
         * Begin creating the fixed price item.
         */
        $item = new Types\ItemType();
        /**
         * We want a multiple quantity fixed price listing.
         */
        $item->ListingType = Enums\ListingTypeCodeType::C_FIXED_PRICE_ITEM;
        $item->Quantity = 99;
        /**
         * Let the listing be automatically renewed every 30 days until cancelled.
         */
        $item->ListingDuration = Enums\ListingDurationCodeType::C_GTC;
        /**
         * The cost of the item is $19.99.
         * Note that we don't have to specify a currency as eBay will use the site id
         * that we provided earlier to determine that it will be United States Dollars (USD).
         */
        $item->StartPrice = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 19.99));
        /**
         * Allow buyers to submit a best offer.
         */
        $item->BestOfferDetails = new Types\BestOfferDetailsType();
        $item->BestOfferDetails->BestOfferEnabled = true;
        /**
         * Automatically accept best offers of $17.99 and decline offers lower than $15.99.
         */
        $item->ListingDetails = new Types\ListingDetailsType();
        $item->ListingDetails->BestOfferAutoAcceptPrice = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 17.99));
        $item->ListingDetails->MinimumBestOfferPrice = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 15.99));
        /**
         * Provide a title and description and other information such as the item's location.
         * Note that any HTML in the title or description must be converted to HTML entities.
         */
        $item->Title = 'H2 Bits &amp; Bobs 4';
        $item->Description = '&lt;H1&gt;H2 Bits &amp; Bobs&lt;/H1&gt;&lt;p&gt;Just some stuff I found.&lt;/p&gt;';
        $item->SKU = 'ABC-001';
        $item->Country = 'US';
        $item->Location = 'Beverly Hills';
        $item->PostalCode = '90210';
        /**
         * This is a required field.
         */
        $item->Currency = 'USD';
        /**
         * Display a picture with the item.
         */
        $item->PictureDetails = new Types\PictureDetailsType();
        $item->PictureDetails->GalleryType = Enums\GalleryTypeCodeType::C_GALLERY;
        $item->PictureDetails->PictureURL = array('https://pixabay.com/get/1d9c26b3a1355d638606/1434976441/rosa-817121_1280.jpg?direct');
        /**
         * List item in the Books > Audiobooks (29792) category.
         */
        $item->PrimaryCategory = new Types\CategoryType();
        $item->PrimaryCategory->CategoryID = '29792';
        /**
         * Tell buyers what condition the item is in.
         * For the category that we are listing in the value of 1000 is for Brand New.
         */
        $item->ConditionID = 1000;
        /**
         * Buyers can use one of two payment methods when purchasing the item.
         * Visa / Master Card
         * PayPal
         * The item will be dispatched within 1 business days once payment has cleared.
         * Note that you have to provide the PayPal account that the seller will use.
         * This is because a seller may have more than one PayPal account.
         */
        $item->PaymentMethods = array(
            'VisaMC',
            'PayPal'
        );
        $item->PayPalEmailAddress = 'example@example.com';
        $item->DispatchTimeMax = 1;
        /**
         * Setting up the shipping details.
         * We will use a Flat shipping rate for both domestic and international.
         */
        $item->ShippingDetails = new Types\ShippingDetailsType();
        $item->ShippingDetails->ShippingType = Enums\ShippingTypeCodeType::C_FLAT;
        /**
         * Create our first domestic shipping option.
         * Offer the Economy Shipping (1-10 business days) service at $2.00 for the first item.
         * Additional items will be shipped at $1.00.
         */
        $shippingService = new Types\ShippingServiceOptionsType();
        $shippingService->ShippingServicePriority = 1;
        $shippingService->ShippingService = 'Other';
        $shippingService->ShippingServiceCost = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 2.00));
        $shippingService->ShippingServiceAdditionalCost = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 1.00));
        $item->ShippingDetails->ShippingServiceOptions[] = $shippingService;
        /**
         * Create our second domestic shipping option.
         * Offer the USPS Parcel Select (2-9 business days) at $3.00 for the first item.
         * Additional items will be shipped at $2.00.
         */
        $shippingService = new Types\ShippingServiceOptionsType();
        $shippingService->ShippingServicePriority = 2;
        $shippingService->ShippingService = 'USPSParcel';
        $shippingService->ShippingServiceCost = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 3.00));
        $shippingService->ShippingServiceAdditionalCost = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 2.00));
        $item->ShippingDetails->ShippingServiceOptions[] = $shippingService;
        /**
         * Create our first international shipping option.
         * Offer the USPS First Class Mail International service at $4.00 for the first item.
         * Additional items will be shipped at $3.00.
         * The item can be shipped Worldwide with this service.
         */
        $shippingService = new Types\InternationalShippingServiceOptionsType();
        $shippingService->ShippingServicePriority = 1;
        $shippingService->ShippingService = 'USPSFirstClassMailInternational';
        $shippingService->ShippingServiceCost = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 4.00));
        $shippingService->ShippingServiceAdditionalCost = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 3.00));
        $shippingService->ShipToLocation = array('WorldWide');
        $item->ShippingDetails->InternationalShippingServiceOption[] = $shippingService;
        /**
         * Create our second international shipping option.
         * Offer the USPS Priority Mail International (6-10 business days) service at $5.00 for the first item.
         * Additional items will be shipped at $4.00.
         * The item will only be shipped to the following locations with this service.
         * N. and S. America
         * Canada
         * Australia
         * Europe
         * Japan
         */
        $shippingService = new Types\InternationalShippingServiceOptionsType();
        $shippingService->ShippingServicePriority = 2;
        $shippingService->ShippingService = 'USPSPriorityMailInternational';
        $shippingService->ShippingServiceCost = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 5.00));
        $shippingService->ShippingServiceAdditionalCost = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => 4.00));
        $shippingService->ShipToLocation = array(
            'Americas',
            'CA',
            'AU',
            'Europe',
            'JP'
        );
        $item->ShippingDetails->InternationalShippingServiceOption[] = $shippingService;
        /**
         * The return policy.
         * Returns are accepted.
         * A refund will be given as money back.
         * The buyer will have 14 days in which to contact the seller after receiving the item.
         * The buyer will pay the return shipping cost.
         */
        $item->ReturnPolicy = new Types\ReturnPolicyType();
        $item->ReturnPolicy->ReturnsAcceptedOption = 'ReturnsAccepted';
        $item->ReturnPolicy->RefundOption = 'MoneyBack';
        $item->ReturnPolicy->ReturnsWithinOption = 'Days_14';
        $item->ReturnPolicy->ShippingCostPaidByOption = 'Buyer';
        /**
         * Finish the request object.
         */
        $request->Item = $item;
        /**
         * Send the request to the AddFixedPriceItem service operation.
         *
         * For more information about calling a service operation, see:
         * http://devbay.net/sdk/guides/getting-started/#service-operation
         */
        $response = $this->service->addFixedPriceItem($request);
        /**
         * Output the result of calling the service operation.
         *
         * For more information about working with the service response object, see:
         * http://devbay.net/sdk/guides/getting-started/#response-object
         */
        if ( isset($response->Errors) )
        {
            foreach ( $response->Errors as $error )
            {
                printf("%s: %s\n%s\n\n", $error->SeverityCode === Enums\SeverityCodeType::C_ERROR ? 'Error' : 'Warning', $error->ShortMessage, $error->LongMessage
                );
            }
        }
        if ( $response->Ack !== 'Failure' )
        {
            printf("The item was listed to the eBay Sandbox with the Item number %s\n", $response->ItemID
            );
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Did you post your actual test and prod tokens on this question?

Comment: yes, the tokens are production and test token below

Comment: Then you've given out the secrets for this account. Anyone can use it.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know that. In fact i'm new in ebay dev program. That is my first integration and i really don't know how to do it. Can you help me ?

Comment: Unsure if this is it, and I'm not a `Php` dev (am .`Net`). Literally hit this a few days ago, so check that you are sending _all_ the required data to make calls. - in my case, I was missing `eBay username` (the eBay user for the store I'm making calls for - aka "context"). Hth...

Comment: Thanks alot. My code above is working. The problem was in ebay account settings.
If someone want to integrate ebay, first he has to create ebay seller account and to link it to PayPal account. It's good if you make automatic payment with PayPal for ebay fees.